# GLMNet convergence issue for penalized regression

Tags: r, social-networking, glmnet, convergence

I am working on network models for political networks. One of the things I am doing is penalized inference. I am using an adaptive lasso approach by setting a penalty factor for glmnet. I have various parameters in my model: `alphas` and `phis`. The `alphas` are fixed effects so I want to keep them in the model while the `phis` are being penalized.

I have starting coefficients from the MLE estimation process of `glm()` to compute the adaptive weights that are set through the penalty factor of `glmnet()`.

This is the code:

```
# Generate Generalized Linear Model
GenLinMod = glm(y ~ X, family = "poisson")
# Set coefficients
coefficients = coef(GenLinMod)
# Set penalty
penalty = 1/(coefficients[-1])^2
# Protect alphas
penalty[1:(n-1)] = 0

# Generate Generalized Linear Model with adaptive lasso procedure
GenLinModNet = glmnet(XS, y, family = "poisson", penalty.factor = penalty, standardize = FALSE)
```

For some networks this code executes just fine, however I have certain networks for which I get these errors:

```
Error: Matrices must have same number of columns in rbind2(.Call(dense_to_Csparse, x), y)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: from glmnet Fortran code (error code -1); Convergence for 1th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
2: In getcoef(fit, nvars, nx, vnames) :
  an empty model has been returned; probably a convergence issue
```

The odd thing is that they all use the same code, so I am wondering if it is a data problem.
Additional information:

+In one case I have over 500 `alphas` and 21 `phis` and these errors appear, in another case that does not work I have 200 `alphas` and 28 `phis`. But on the other hand I have a case with over 600 `alphas` and 28 `phis` and it converges nicely.

+I have tried settings for `lambda.min.ratio` and `nlambda` to no avail.

Additional question: Is the first entry of penalty the one associated with the intercept? Or is it added automatically by `glmnet()`? I did not find clarity about this in the `glmnet` vignette. My thoughts are that I shouldn't include a term for the intercept, since it's said that the penalty is internally rescaled to sum `nvars` and I assume the intercept isn't one of my variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think I have found the root of the problem.

I've tried to use all kinds of manual lambda sequences, even trying very large starting lambda's (1000's). This all seemed to do no good at all. However, when I tried without penalizing the alpha's, everything would converge nicely. So it probably has something to do with the amount of unpenalized variables. Maybe keeping all alpha's unpenalized forces glmnet in some divergent state. Maybe there is some sort of collinearity going on. My "solution", which is basically just doing something else, is to penalize the alpha's with the same weigth that is used for one of the phi's. This works on the assumption that some phi's are significant and the alpha's can be just as significant, instead of being fixed (which makes them infinitely significant). I'm not completely satisfied, because this is just a different approach, but it might be interesting to note that it probably has something to do with the amount of unpenalized variables.

Also, to answer my additional question: In the glmnet vignette it says that the penalty term is internally rescaled to sum to nvars. Since the intercept is not one of the variables, my guess is that it is not needed in the penalty term. Though, I've tried with both including and excluding the term, results seem to be the same. So maybe glmnet automatically removes it if it detects that the length is +1 of what it should be.